# JScript Check if element exists and remove it

Tags: javascript, element, exists

I'm trying to write a simple function in javascript to check if an element exists in the DOM and if it does remove, and if it doesn't, append it to the page, so far i've got this

```
        if document.contains(document.getElementById("submitbutton") {
            document.getElementById("submitbutton").remove();
}   else {
        lastDiv.appendChild(submitButton);  
        }
```

(lastDiv is just the div I want to append the div 'submitButton' to)
Yet i'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"

Any help?
I'm aware this is a very newbie question, sorry about that

Comment: We need more code than this.  Where is `myFunction`?

Comment: its a very long function, but this is the only part of it that is causing an error, i've debugged the rest

Comment: @howdybaby No you haven't, there is a problem with `myFunction`

Comment: but when i remove these lines of code from the function, the rest of it runs fine, yet when I add these lines in, the whole thing breaks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the code, `if` statements require parens

```
if (document.contains(document.getElementById("submitbutton"))) {
            document.getElementById("submitbutton").remove();
}   else {
        lastDiv.appendChild(submitButton);  
}
```

Comment: if (document.contains(document.getElementById("submitbutton"))  should change to if (document.contains(document.getElementById("submitbutton")))  You forgot one param

Answer (score 3):

Check if element exists:

```
function removeID(_id ){ 
    var e=document.getElementById(_id);
    if(e!==null) e.remove();
}
removeID( "myElement" );
```